# How to pass argument to npm script with AND operator

Tags: node.js, npm

I have one npm script:

```js
scripts: {
  "deploy": "npm run build && ./deploy.sh"
}
```

we can pass an argument to the script: `npm run deploy -- --env=prod`

but the problem is the command before the AND operator didn't get the argument injected, is there a way to pass the argument with the && operator?

I am expecting a way like：

```js
scripts: {
  "start": "npm run build -- arg[0] && ./deploy.sh"
}
```

or any correct or better way to get there, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I try in this way and it seams to work

```
"start":"npm run build -- {{process.argv}} && ./deploy.sh"
```